# Trigger and event from Spring MVC to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, spring-mvc

I am creating a notification app for SPRING MVC. I am trying nodejs for this purpose.

My question is how can i send any event that happend in spring to nodejs server so that it will notify the user from inside nodejs.

`In short:` SPRING MVC GOT A NEW COMMENT ----> SPRING WILL SEND A NEW COMMENT EVENT TO NODEJS SERVER ---> NODEJS SEVER WILL SEND THIS NOTIFICATION TO BROWSER CLIENT.

Comment: Are you using [tag:websocket]s with [tag:node.js]?

Comment: You can use a [tag:message-queue] for this; send notifications from your **Spring MVC** app to the **Message Queue**, consume them from your **Node** application (send messages to clients via **WebSockets** for example.)

Comment: `@ fardjad` i am using socket.io

Comment: `fardjad` an example would be better. Can you a give a full example.